# Why are my calculated normalized difference indices maxima bigger +1?

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-snap, results

I’m wondering about the results of my indices, e.g. the NBR maximum is +1.37 (see picture below),and as we all know the NBR (like any other normalized difference index) should be between -1 and 1…
[image: NBR on a self created forest mask]

For background information:

- I’m using Landsat Data of the Coll. 2 Lvl. 2 in September 1992, 2003 and 2018 (I’m relatively new to remote sensing and wanted to make sure that I don’t do anything wrong with the preprocessing steps). The years 1992 and 2018 are all good!

I’m only interested on forests, so I’m running my indices (also calculated NDVI and NDMI) on a self created forest mask.

- already tried out if this mask was somehow the reason for fail – it wasn’t, the results are even more confusing!
  [image: NBR for my whole study area]
  I ran the calculation for another year (Sep 2005) and there was the same error, I even deinstalled and reinstalled SNAP, but the error is still there.

If I do a dark substraction before, the min-max. values are between -1 and 1 **BUT** im using Lvl. 2.2 products! I’m sure that I should definitely not do this (it’s like a double atmospheric correction and “falsification” of the data, I guess) – so what is my mistake?? What can I do?

Comment: Found the solution: it's due to the clouds in the scene!